# How to amend my javascript script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript: http://www.mastermind-solutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/index.html

here's html:

```
<div class="rss-popup">
  <a href="feed-link" id="rss-icon">RSS Feed</a>
  <em>Subscribe to our RSS Feed</em>
</div>
```

What I need is to get this jquery animation on a simple div without a link. My html which I need to animate: `<span class="tickercontainer" id="votes<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo $votes; ?></span>` How should I amend this effect to make it work in my case?

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".rss-popup a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
  }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
  });
});
```

css:

```
div.rss-popup em {
  background: url("images/bubble.png") no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 49px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  left: -0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

.rss-popup {
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#rss-icon {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: url("images/icon.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it animated on hover, just have this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tickercontainer").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
  });
});
```

What you need is different selector, then animate the "current" element.

Comment: I tried this and its not correct. Actually what it does is on hover .ticekrcontainer goes up and disappears.

Comment: You probably need to apply the same CSS on your `tickercontainer` class.